# Use of keypad in Digital Lab Sim of Mars simulator

Tags: mars-simulator

I do not achieve to control keypad of the Digital Lab Sim tool of Mars 4.2.

According to the directions in the help "Byte value at address 0xFFFF0014 : receive row and column of the key pressed, 0 if not key pressed ". Nevertheless, if you read that memory position it does not work. Next simple sequence should read the keypad, but it does not work

```
ini:
lui $1,0xffff

lw $2,0x0014($1)


j ini
```

It always returns a 0 in spite of pressing any key of the tools.

I have no problem with the seven segment digit of this tool at all. It is quite easy to use through the address 0xFFFF0012. Nevertheless, no way with the keypad of this tool

Does anybody know how to read the keypad of the Digital Lab Sim of Mars 4.2?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself.

Before reading a key, you have to select the row. The next sequence check the three rows (and it works):

```
        sub $0,$0,$0
        lui $2,0xffff       # Base address IO
main:        
        addi $3,$0,0x01     # bit 0 =1 for row 1 
        sb $3,0x0012($2)    # Selection row 1 (write on port 0xFFFF 0012)
        lb $4,0x0014($2)    # $4= code of pressed key of row 1 ($4=0 if not pressed)
        bne $4,$0,row1      # if some key of row 1 was pressed -> go row1
                            # test of row 2
        addi $3,$0,0x02     # bit 1 =1 for row 2 
        sb $3,0x0012($2)    
        lb $4,0x0014($2)    
        bne $4,$0,row2
                            # test of row 3
        addi $3,$0,0x04     # bit 2 =1 for row 3 
        sb $3,0x0012($2)    
        lb $4,0x0014($2)    
        bne $4,$0,row3
                            # test of row 4
        addi $3,$0,0x08     # bit 3 =1 for row 4 
        sb $3,0x0012($2)    
        lb $4,0x0014($2)    
        bne $4,$0,row4
        j main
row1:  # $4 has the code of the pressed key of this row
row2:  # $4 has the code of the pressed key of this row
row3:  # $4 has the code of the pressed key of this row
row4:  # $4 has the code of the pressed key of this row
```